# Isabelle: difference between A * 1 and A ** mat 1

Tags: isabelle

What is the difference between `*` and `**` for matrices
and also A * 1`and`A ** mat 1`?

Example:

```
lemma myexample:
  fixes A :: "('a::comm_ring_1)^'n∷finite^'n∷finite"
  shows "(A * 1 = A) ∧ (A ** (mat 1) = A)" 
 by (metis comm_semiring_1_class.normalizing_semiring_rules(12) matrix_mul_rid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices in Isabelle are defined simply as vectors of vectors, so the `*` on matrices is inherited from vectors, and `*` on vectors is just componentwise multiplication. Therefore, you have `(A*B) $ i $ j = A $ i $ j * B $ i $ j`, i.e. `*` is entry-by-entry multiplication of a matrix. Whether this is actually useful anywhere, I do not know – I don't think so. It's probably just an artifact of defining matrices as vectors of vectors. It might have been better to do a proper typedef for matrices and define `*` as the *right* matrix multiplication on them, but there must have been some reason why that was not done – maybe just because it's more work and a lot of copypasted code.

`**` is the *proper* matrix multiplication. `mat x` is simply the matrix that has `x` on its diagonal and `0` everywhere else, so of course, `mat 1` is the identity matrix and `A ** mat 1 = A`.

The matrix `1` however is, again, an artifact from the vector definition; the n-dimensional vector `1` is simply defined as the vector that has n components, all of which are `1`. Consequently, the matrix `1` is the matrix whose entries are all `1`, and then of course, `A * 1 = A`. This does not seem useful to me in any way.

Comment: The type of `*` in Isabelle requires both of the arguments to have the same type; this means using `*` for matrix multiplication would only work for _square_ matrices. It might be useful to have a type like `('a,'n)squarematrix`, but nobody has contributed such a library as of yet.

Comment: I agree that the definitions of pointwise multiplication, numerals, etc. for vectors are mathematically nonstandard and mostly useless. This is why I never migrated these class instantiations into `Finite_Cartesian_Product.thy` where the vector type is defined. It would probably be better to split those instantiations further into an optional import.